# Ember store refresh issue! Error: could not respond to event didChangeData in state rootState.loaded.updated.uncommitted

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to load my data using a separate query to the server after the records get dirty in the store. The updated values are sent to the server and relevant actions are performed using a custom ajax call and handled at the server side to update all the related records. But when the data is loaded again I get the above mentioned error. 
The possible reason could be, since the records are dirty in the store, and without committing the store I am trying to load the data again, it is giving me the error. So, I tried to do an "Application.defaultTransaction.rollback()". It removes those records from the updated bucket, but the "key" in the updated bucket (the object type) still exists and I still get the error. Can anyone help me with this?

*In short: is there a way to force clean the store or move all the objects in created/updated/inflight buckets to **clean** bucket?*

Comment: Did you call store.didSaveRecord() when the server respond ? I think the job done by DS.(REST)Adapter should be done in your case too.

Comment: That's not the issue. I have parallel API calls set up and do not use data store default put/post requests.
I had to basically do a store.get('defaultTransaction').rollback() which I tried earlier but probably in a wrong place. Anyways the issue is resolved. Thanks

Comment: I understood you were not commiting, but manually posting record. You have two ways of moving records in a clean state, either by doing rollback as you do here, either by calling store.didSaveRecord(), passing the record, and the new data hash. In your case rollback works fine for you, so +1 :)

Comment: I wasn't able to find a didSaveRecord method in ember-data. Which version are you referring to?

Comment: euh, in master: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L858

Comment: probably I am using an earlier version which dint have it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Application.store.get('defaultTransaction').rollback() will remove any dirty objects in the store and take it to the initial state.
There is an open issue for store.rollback() too which might be an alternative when merged to master.
https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/350#issuecomment-9578563